# How to hide the text displayed on status bar when I make an ajax call using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have been using Ajax with JavaScript. All such calls are made with a mouse hover on a particular text. The mouse hovering shows the JavaScript method being called at the bottom of the status bar. I have seen at some websites where this is totally masked. No display at the status bar.

Is it possible to do it in JavaScript, without going for jQuery like frameworks?

The sample code is given below.

**JavaScript Code**

```
<script language="javascript">
function doAjaxSearch()
{
    //1. Get the Input value
   var inputTxt = document.getElementById('inputTxt').value;

    //2. Get XMLHttpRequest (XHR)
   var xhttp = getXMLHttpRequest(); //separate method gives a 'xhttpr'

   var url = "getTasks";
   var params = "input="+inputTxt;
   var httpMethod = 'GET';

   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
   {
         if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200)
         {
              console.log(xhttp.responseText);
              //prepare the response
              prepareOutput(xhttp.responseText);
         }
   };

   xhttp.open(httpMethod, url+"?"+params, true);
   xhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
 //rest of the code omitted for brevity..
 <input type=text name="inputTxt" id="inputTxt" size=20/>
 <a href="javascript:doAjaxSearch()">Search</a>
```

I could always see that the bottom left of the status bar showing the text "javascript:doAjaxSearch()".

I want to hide this display in the status bar of the browser, in the plain JavaScript itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: i did not get you sorry

Comment: If you don't want jQuery solution, why do you talk about it and tag your question with it?!  And what about providing MCVE so we can test it?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code, in order to provide a good answer for you.

Comment: @a-wolff, Thanks for the hint. I have just removed the jQuery tag. I will also provide the code for others as requested for everyone' s better understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding event listeners to javascript elements will not show a message in the status bar when hovering over them:

```
function searchEventHandler(ev)
{
    // do something
}

el.addEventListener('click', searchEventHandler);
```

And can be removed later, if necessary with:

```
el.removeEventListener('click', searchEventHandler);
```

**EDIT:**
Credit to RDeving for the improvement for removing event handlers as well.

**UPDATE:**
You see the status message because you are using `<a>` tags to invoke your javascript function. Change this to a `<span>` and add an event handler as outlined above to execute your click event.

```
<script>
    function searchEventHandler(ev)
    {
        // do something
    }
    var search = document.getElementById('search');
    search.addEventListener('click', searchEventHandler);
</script>
<span id='search' style='cursor: pointer;'>Search</span>
```

Comment: Well, i didn't know this behaviour, now i have to test it but looks quite strange as behaviour imo

Comment: Ok now following your edit, i think this is more correct because i didn't thing `el.(on)click` would have different behaviour regarding the adress bar

Comment: I made assumptions about the asker's code, which I shouldn't have done. We all know what they say about assumptions, after all! Speaking of code, the asker really should provide some.

Comment: About this, you should avoid using anonymous functions in event listeners, it should be like "el.addEventListener('click',FnThatFiresOnClick);", so, when you are done with it you can use "el.removeEventListener('click',FnThatFiresOnClick);"

Comment: @Matt-SL, it is perfect! Helps me achieve what I wanted. However it masks the mouse pointer icon rather it shows a straight cursor during the hovering. Any help that I can still give an impression to the user that it is a link that is clickable and clicked?

Comment: @RDeving, thank you for the great tip! I am just wondering when and where I should remove the eventListener? Is it at the end of my Javascript method being called?

Comment: @itsraghz I added the cursor style you were looking for on the `<span>` tag. If you want it to show that it has been clicked, you could change the search element's text colour inside the event handler.

Comment: @Matt-SL, thank you  very much! It works like a charm. Just one more thing, can you please advice me on when and where I should use the removeEventListener piece?

Comment: @itsraghz you will probably never need to use it. It's only use is if you had a situation where you wanted to disable the search button.

Comment: @Matt-SL, thank you. I really appreciate your understanding and support. You deserve a cookie! :)